# Installing Apache PHP module on amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, php-5.6, apache2.2

I am using `Amazon linux` with apache and `PHP` installed.

I get the following:

```
>httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.31 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar  7 2016 23:50:21
```

and

```
>php -v
PHP 5.6.19 (cli) (built: Apr  1 2016 22:29:27) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

However, When I request a PHP page through the apache server, the PHP code is not executed.

I checked through the `httpd.conf` file and there is no PHP module present.

also,

```
ls /etc/httpd/modules/ | grep php
```

returns nothing

I need to install the PHP 5.6 module for Apache. How can I do this?

Comment: you have installed PHP first and then Apache, which is why Apache is not recognizing PHP. remove php , then install it , and restart Apache. You should be through

Comment: I did what you suggested. I reinstalled php56 and Apache 2.4 automatically got installed.

Comment: It is working, however it just created a new [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109038/installing-mod-wsgi-module-for-apache-2-4) different from this question.