# Installing mod_wsgi module for Apache 2.4

Tags: python-2.7, mod-wsgi, apache2.4

I have a Python Flask-restful app. I want to serve it through the Apache server instead of the development server.

I have the following in `http.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName batch-autoscaling-algos

        WSGIDaemonProcess optimzation_app user=mv2 group=mv2 threads=1
        WSGIScriptAlias / /projects/mv2/millvi-auto-scaling/batch-auto-scaling/api/htdocs/optimization.wsgi

        <Directory /projects/mv2/millvi-auto-scaling/batch-auto-scaling/api/htdocs/optimization_app>
            WSGIProcessGroup optimization_app
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Previously, I had PHP 5.6 and Apache 2.2 installed. So, I installed `mod_wsgi` simply by `yum search mod-wsgi` and then   doing `yum install` based on the appropriate Python version, so it worked well.

Now, I reinstalled PHP5.6 which automatically upgraded by Apache to version 2.4.

At this point when I do `yum search mod-wsgi`, it says `No matches found`. If I try to simply restart apache with the above mentioned configuration, it says `Invalid command 'WSGIDaemonProcess', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`.

What is the correct way to install `mod_wsgi`. I am using Amazon Linux and Python version 2.7.